# line_profiler to trace built in functions

Tags: python, profiler, line-profiler

I know use profile or cprofile library can profile the detail CPU time for given piece of code, but it cannot specify a given function. And I know line_profiler can trace a certain function but it cannot trace deep into the third part library or build-in function was called. Is there any method to combine both library's result to trace a given function and all the sub-function within it?